# Deployed Web Application Requests for User Name and Password

Tags: domain, web, application

Deployed Web Application Requests for User Name and Password

I recently deployed a .NET web application into the server.

Authentication mode is set to Windows (since the application is accessible only to Intranet users.

Testing some machines, the application loads up properly.  For some machines, a logon dialog window appears asking for User Name or Password.  These dialog windows are those that you also normally see when you are trying to log into a Windows domain.

Any idea why this happens randomly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using IE.

There are a couple of things to look at:

1. Are the machines in question joined to the domain?
2. For the machines in question, is a domain user (with appropriate privileges) logged into Windows on that machine?

Comment: 1. Yes, machines are all in the same domain.
2. Yes, the user logged in to the domain.